# Rails 4 Subdomain Route to Tumblr site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have blog.website.com that is actually a tumblr site.  ( the tumblr name is covered )

I want to write a route for it because that seems like the rails way to do it. Create a blog_path

so I tried a few things, but none of the mhave worked.

I am not totally sure what to put for the controller, but I have this. The thing is the view belongs to a whole other website (tumblr), so I am not even sure this is right.

```
def blog 
end
```

Thank you

Comment: This question is a but unclear, are you trying to redirect to a tumblr site from a rails app?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you need but I guess you are looking for this:

```
get "/blog" => redirect("http://blog.tumblr.com"), :as => :blog
```

This will route `/blog` to `blog.tumblr.com`